# addservlet vs createservlet servlet context methods

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-3.0, servletcontextlistener

I'm exploring Servlet 3.0 features for programmatically adding servlets to the context and I can't completely get the differences between:

1. [createServlet(Class<T> clazz)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#createServlet-java.lang.Class-)
2. [addServlet(String servletName, Class<? extends Servlet> servletClass)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#addServlet-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-)

Considering that:

- method (1) gives an instance of the servlet;
- method (1) may throw an exception, whereas method (2) does not.

What's the use for (1)?
I'm using (2) in a `ServletContextListener` and everything seems to work without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The rationale for `createServlet` is stated in the Javadoc:

> The returned Servlet instance may be further customized before it is
>   registered with this ServletContext via a call to
>   addServlet(String,Servlet). This method introspects the given clazz for the following **annotations**: ... In addition, this method supports **resource injection** if the given clazz represents a Managed Bean.

So the API allows you to do the following:

```
// create a servlet, process annotations and do injections
MyServlet myServlet = context.createServlet(MyServlet.class);

// further customization
myServlet.runSpecialInit(someArg);   

// register
context.addServlet("theName", myServlet);
```

Alternatively you could do the following

```
MyServlet myServlet = new MyServlet();
myServlet.runSpecialInit(someArg);
context.addServlet("theName", myServlet);
```

but contrary to the first snippet this will not evaluate annotations and do injections.

And you can think of `addServlet(String servletName, Class<? extends Servlet> servletClass)` as an abbreviation for

```
Servlet servlet = createServlet(servletClass);
addServlet(servletName, servlet);
```